# nvim-tree.lua installed through Vundle but its commands don't exist

Tags: linux, neovim

I installed [nvim-tree.lua](https://github.com/kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua) using the Vundle plugin manager in my `init.vim`:

```
call vundle#begin()
    Plugin 'kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua'
call vundle#end()
source $HOME/.config/nvim/nvim_tree.vim
```

The nvim_tree.vim file includes:

```
nnoremap <C-n> :NvimTreeToggle<CR>
```

Sure enough, calling `:PluginList` lists the plugin correctly.

Checking bundle's runtime path `~/.vim/bundle/`, the plugin files are all there.

However calling `:NvimTreeToggle` produces the error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: NvimTreeToggle
```

Comment: I don't know whether it will help, but maybe try using plugin manager more suitable for Neovim? Vundle is outdated even for Vim

Comment: Who use vundle in 21 century? Use vim-plug or better packer.nvim.

Answer (score 9):

Turns out I completely ignored a change in the latest commit:

> Options are currently being migrated into the setup function, you need to `run require'nvim-tree'.setup()` in your personal configurations.

So after `:lua require'nvim-tree'.setup()` everything works fine.

Comment: I just had this same problem and this is the fix.

Comment: If I run this in the nvim command line it works, but if I put it inside the `init.vim` doesn't have any effect. Any one knows why?

Comment: @DavidMagalhães I had the same problem, but when I moved `:lua require'nvim-tree'.setup()` in my last line of `init.vim`, it started working fine (and it's gorgeous! )